# Layout two controls on a line in a stretchable WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout

Here's a fairly common UI pattern: Text box that contains a path to the left, and a Browse button to the right of it. If the window resizes, the button stays to the right, but the text box stretches to reveal more/less of the path. So in the good old days of anchors, the button would be anchored to the right and the text box would be anchored both left and right.

Trying to replicate this in WPF seems to be worryingly difficult.

If I create a new window, it comes with a Grid layout by default. I place my text box to the left and size it appropriately, then place the button to its right. HorizontalAlignment for the text box is Stretch and for the button it is Right.

In my mind, this works as described, but in real life the text box doesn't resize at all, but instead tries to center itself in the window, while the button acts as expected. What gives?

Here is my XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="241" d:DesignWidth="414" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="12,11,101,0" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,11,12,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would create another `GridControl` with two columns, one with a fixed width for `Browse` button and another one for the `TextBox`.

```
<Grid>            
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions> 
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `DockPanel` and set `LastChildFill` property to `true` to ensure that the textbox uses all the available space:

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="true">
  <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right">Browse</Button>
  <TextBox>Content</TextBox>
</DockPanel>
```